# How to apply a sliding animation on ImageView without knowing its current coordiates?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an ImageView some where in the center of the screen, and I want to make it "slide" a few pixels to the right, preferably without having to find out its current x and y coordinates.

I saw something called `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`, but I don't think it's what I think it means. When the following code runs, the image view will be dragged to the top left corner. So I suspect `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0` means "zero" rather than "stay where you are".

`TranslateAnimation split_slide = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);`

Is there a way I can "slide" just a few pixels on the x-asix without knowing its current coordinates? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). To slide your view (`myView`) 5 pixels over:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myView, "x", myView.getX()+5);
animator.start();
```